# Correspondance between Spec of two polynomial rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose that $K/k$ is a galois extension of number fields. What’s the relation between
$$\text{Spec} k[x_1,\dots,x_n]\quad\text{and} \quad \text{Spec} K[x_1,\dots,x_n]? $$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

The inclusion of rings $i: k[x_1,..., x_n]\hookrightarrow K[x_1,..., x_n]$ gives a continuous map $SpecK[x_1,..., x_n]\rightarrow Speck[x_1,..., x_n]$.

Under this map, if $k= \mathbb{R}$ and $K= \mathbb{C}$, the point corresponding to the prime ideal $(x- i)$ goes to the point corresponding to $(x^2+1)$, as does the point corresponding to $(x+i) $. Galois automorphisms are like symmetries of this map.

If I recall correctly, the image of this morphism is dense.